How can I use the function call feature in a conversation loop in python openai?s
So im using the feature of function calling of openai to make an assistant bot, in this case the function im using is used to generate a workout plan, though im not understanding how im supposed to take the content part only of the output and use it in a conversation loop every time, this is my code for now:
from openai import OpenAI
import openai
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json
import random
from typing import List, Dict
load_dotenv()
client = OpenAI(api_key=os.getenv('API_KEY'))


def get_completion(messages, tools = None, tool_choice = None, model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature = 0):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model = model,
        messages = messages,
        tools = tools,
        tool_choice = tool_choice,
        temperature = temperature
        )
    return response


def generate_workout_plan(fitness_goal, workout_type, duration):
    workouts = {
        "weight_loss": {
            "cardio": ["Running", "Cycling", "Swimming"],
            "strength": ["Bodyweight Squats", "Push-ups", "Burpees"]
        },
        "muscle_gain": {
            "cardio": ["Rowing", "Jump Rope", "Elliptical"],
            "strength": ["Bench Press", "Deadlifts", "Pull-ups"]
        },
        "endurance": {
            "cardio": ["Long-distance Running", "Hiking", "Rowing"],
            "strength": ["High-rep Squats", "Dumbbell Snatches", "Kettlebell Swings"]
        }
    }
    
    
    if fitness_goal in workouts and workout_type in workouts[fitness_goal]:
        selected_workouts = workouts[fitness_goal][workout_type]
    else:
        selected_workouts = []


    workout_plan = []
    for i in range(duration):
        if selected_workouts:
            workout_plan.append(random.choice(selected_workouts))
    
    return workout_plan

tools = [
    {
    "type":"function",
    "function":{
    "name": "generate_workout_plan",
    "description": "Generates a personalized workout plan based on fitness goals, type of workout, and duration.",
    "parameters": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "fitness_goal": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The user's fitness goal (e.g., weight_loss, muscle_gain, endurance)."
            },
            "workout_type": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The type of workout (e.g., cardio, strength)."
            },
            "duration": {
                "type": "integer",
                "description": "The number of workout sessions to include in the plan."
            }
        },
        "required": ["fitness_goal", "workout_type", "duration"],
        "additionalProperties": False
        }
    }
}

]

messages = [
    {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Generate a 5-session workout plan for muscle gain focusing on strength exercises."
    }
]


available_tools = {
    "generate_workout_plan": generate_workout_plan
}



def extract_tool_calls(response) -> Dict:
    tool_calls = response.choices[0].message.tool_calls

    result = {
        "role":"assistant",
        "tool_calls":[]
    }

    for tool_call in tool_calls:
        converted_call = {
            "id":tool_call.id,
            "type":tool_call.type,
            "function":{
                "name":tool_call.function.name,
                "arguments":json.loads(tool_call.function.arguments)
            }
        }
        result["tool_calls"].append(converted_call)
    return result

def get_tool_response(tool_call):
    tool_name = tool_call.function.name 
    tool_arguments = json.loads(tool_call.function.arguments) 
    
    if tool_name in available_tools:
        tool_function = available_tools[tool_name]
        parameters = []
        for key in tool_arguments:
            parameters.append(tool_arguments[key])
        tool_response = tool_function(*parameters)
    else:
        tool_response = {"error": f"Tool '{tool_name}' not found."}
    
    return tool_response




def process_append_messages(messages,Debug=False):
    response = get_completion(messages,tools=tools)

    if Debug:
        print(response)
    
    message = response.choices[0].message
    if Debug:
        print(message)

    if message.tool_calls:
        tool_call_info = extract_tool_calls(response)
        if Debug:
            print(tool_call_info)
        
        messages.append(tool_call_info)
        tool_call = message.tool_calls[0]
        tool_response = get_tool_response(tool_call)
        tool_response_info = {
            "role":"tool",
            "content":json.dumps(tool_response),
            "tool_call_id":tool_call.id
            }
        messages.append(tool_response_info)

    if message.content:
        content_info = {
            "role":"assistant",
            "content":message.content
        }
        messages.append(content_info)
    return messages







Here is my output if I call the function (process_append_messages) and print it:

[{'role': 'user', 'content': 'Generate a 5-session workout plan for
muscle gain focusing on strength exercises.'}, {'role': 'assistant',
'tool_calls': [{'id': 'call_t9QPfgrmE46ww1mG1vWUDnzs', 'type':
'function', 'function': {'name': 'generate_workout_plan', 'arguments':
{'fitness_goal': 'muscle_gain', 'workout_type': 'strength',
'duration': 5}}}]}, {'role': 'tool', 'content': '["Deadlifts",
"Pull-ups", "Pull-ups", "Bench Press", "Pull-ups"]', 'tool_call_id':
'call_t9QPfgrmE46ww1mG1vWUDnzs'}]

I tried making a conversation loop code in this way but it did not work :
all_messages = []

while True:
    user_message = input("user: ") 
    if user_message.lower() == "exit":
        break
    final_response = process_append_messages(messages)
    all_messages.append({'role': 'user', 'content': user_message})
    all_messages.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': final_response[-1]['content']})
    if final_response[-1]['role'] == 'assistant':
        print(f"assistant: {final_response[-1]['content']}")
all_messages = []

while True:
    user_message = input("user: ") 
    if user_message.lower() == "exit":
        break
    final_response = process_append_messages(messages)
    all_messages.append({'role': 'user', 'content': user_message})
    all_messages.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': final_response[-1]['content']})
    if final_response[-1]['role'] == 'assistant':
        print(f"assistant: {final_response[-1]['content']}")

